Why did Jean say the word "Unexpected"?
Jean suddenly stops having sex with Oppenheimer, gets out of bed, and stands
naked before a shelf:

Oppenheimer:  Wait, wait, wait.
JEAN: Unexpected.
Oppenheimer: What?
Jean: For a physicist.

Even Oppenheimer, like me, is likely asking for clarification or expressing
confusion about what Jean meant by ‘Unexpected’.”
Why did Jean say the word "Unexpected" ?

You missed the context which is in the next line

OPPENHEIMER: You’ve only got a shelf full of Freud?

She's commenting on what books he has and that the subject matter is not what she expected from a physicist.

